# Importing and rotating/scaling/moving 3D objects in ios/android app

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, 3d-model

I'm making an app on ios and android (preferably ios) and I'm looking for a simplistic way of importing 3d models (.obj) to the app and manipulating them (rotate/scale/translate) using some gestures. Do I use open gles for this or is there a simpler way?